# Any tax advantage for registering a residential house as a business? (I want to apply legal pressure to my landlord)

Tags: united-states, taxes, california

I am just wondering what the tax pros and cons are for listing what should be a residential house as a business in California. The place I was living at was officially registered as a business for my landlord for the time I was there, not residential.

I am asking because I want to legally pressure my landlord. He gave me 100 back on my 2x month deposit of 5k on a place I had been renting for five months. I kept the house in pristine condition, and he has no reasons for taking all the money. Just wondering if I can pressure him legally into giving me most of the deposit. I can understand 300-500 for professional cleaning (although I spent two days general cleaning), but 4.9k is absurd.

Thanks for your help and advice.

Comment: What do you mean by "listing what should be a residential house as a business"?  "Registering" it how?  In any case, depending on your location there may be laws that allow you to apply legal pressure without doing anything like what you describe, but as littleadv says you need to specify your location.

Comment: I understand you have a disagreement about disposition of deposit. I don't exactly understand your gambit for leverage: reporting the property as your home business won't impact the landlord.  If the property was zoned commercial depending on the town you might have some leverage if you report a residential use.

Comment: @user662852 I'm not sure if there is a gambit for leverage, but I was hoping what he is doing is illegal so I could bring that up and use it as leverage for a fair share of the deposit back.

Comment: Whether what he is doing is legally defensible or not, only a lawyer can tell you, and that only after examining the lease. However, taxes and businesses are not useful here; if anything you are likely to get better protection renting as a residence.

Comment: The unfortunate moral: never, ever hand over very high deposits.  :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, in California there's no such thing as registering a place as a business. There's zoning (residential/commercial/mixed/etc), and there's "a business registered at a place". But there's no "place registered as a business". So you better clarify what it is that you think your landlord did. It may be that the place is used for short term rentals, in which case the landlord may have to have registered a business of short term rentals there, depending on the local municipal or county rules.

Specifically regarding the deposit, however, there's a very clear treatment in the California law. The landlord must provide itemized receipt for the amounts out of the deposit that were used, and the prices should be reasonable and based on the actual charges by the actual vendors. If you didn't get such a receipt, or the amounts are bogus and unsubstantiated - [you have protection under the CA law](http://www.dca.ca.gov/publications/landlordbook/sec-deposit.shtml).